# Swype quick emoji input list

Tags: swype, emoticons

Does anyone know where to find the list of the available [intuitive emoji input](http://www.technologytell.com/apple/142693/swype-keyboard-app-gets-new-languages/) keywords? I have looked unsuccessfully.

It will be useful as a reference.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My gf and I have compiled a list of what we have found so far, and are still discovering more.

☺ happy
 wondering
 smile
 sad / cry 
 concerned / worried
 OMG
 tongue / raspberry
 grin
 wink
 asleep 
 sleepy
 scared 
 fear 
 cool
 emo
 stubborn

☝ up / one
 bad / no / thumbs down
 good / yes / thumbs up
 clap
 hello / wave
 hear / ear
smell / nose
 mouth
 eyes / see
 massage

guy / boy
 girl
 couple
 angel
 skull
 ghost
 liberty
 yay
 swim
 run
 kiss

✈ plane
 train
 car
 bus
 bike
⛵ boat 
 trolley

walk / hike
 man
 woman
 baby
 smoke

bird
 dog
 cat
 fish
 whale
 panda
 rabbit / bunny
 monkey
 chicken
 pig
 horse
 sheep
 cow
 tiger

❤ heart
 love
✔ check mark
 trail / footprints
 knife
 gun / shoot
☎ phone
✂ scissors / cut
 box
 money
 atm / cash
 date
⏰ alarm
 shower

music
 guitar
 saxophone
 violin

beer
 drink / martini
 wine
 hamburger / cheeseburger
☕ coffee
 ice cream
 pizza
 donut
 tomato
 bread
 chocolate
 candy
 banana
☕ coffee
☕ tea
 sushi

night
 sun
☔ rain
☁ cloud
❄ snow / cold
 fire / hot

shoe
 shirt
 jam
 couple

Comment: You are amazing my friend :D

Comment: I will add to this when I come across them myself.

Answer (score 5):

Few more I found:

mad  pout  snake  helicopter  atm / cash 
⚾ baseball  football  basketball ⛳ golf ⚽ soccer  tennis  goat  hair  turtle  king / queen / crown  star  crocodile  picture / camera  mouse  lollipop  cake  ski  snowboard  surf  punch  bathroom ⛪ church  toilet  ok  purse  heel / sandal  diamond  ambulance  truck  movie / theater  taxi  beach / palm  tree  koala ⛄ snowman  earth / world  rainbow  penguin  octopus  snail  rat  whale  tv  bowling  pool  bath  battery  key  flashlight  hammer  wrench / tool  trolley  atm / cash  chips

poodle  umbrella  rose  gift drug  dragon  sushi  Halloween  alien  frown  surf ♿ wheelchair  pill  piano  Santa ✋ hand ✌ peace  cookie  game  radio  glasses  smirk